# How to fix 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable’ error in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib-basemap

I've just begun to learn Python. However, there was a problem.

I try to connect it with a curve or a straight line using a few coordinate points.

Or... Can you change this code simple?

first_coordinate

```
A_lon = np.array([126.393, 127.012, 127.545, 128.035, 128.544, 128.768, 129.239])
A_lat = np.array([37.277, 37.553, 37.343, 37.576, 37.486, 37.924, 37.795])

A_lon_new = np.linspace(A_lon.min(), A_lon.max(),500)

f = interp1d(A_lon, A_lat, kind='quadratic')
A_lat_new = f(A_lon_new)

A_x, A_y = map(A_lon, A_lat)
A_x1, A_y1 = map(A_lon_new, A_lat_new)


m.plot (A_x, A_y, "ko", markersize=5)
```

straight_line

```
m.plot(A_x, A_y, color='b', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1.5)
```

curve_line

```
m.scatter (A_x1, A_y1, color='r', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1.5)
```

Second_coordinate

```
B_lon = np.array([126.285, 127.314, 127.653, 128.214, 128.92, 129.057, 129.735])
B_lat = np.array([36.132, 35.847, 35.93, 36.406, 36.102, 36.4, 36.816])

B_lon_new = np.linspace(B_lon.min(), B_lon.max(),500)

f = interp1d(B_lon, B_lat, kind='quadratic')
B_lat_new = f(B_lon_new)

B_x, B_y= map(B_lon, B_lat)
B_x1, B_y1 = map(B_lon_new, B_lat_new)


m.plot (B_x, B_y, "ko", markersize=5)
```

straight_line

```
m.plot (B_x, B_y, color='b', linestyle = '--', linewidth=1.5)
```

curve_line

```
m.plot(B_x1, B_y1, color='r', linestyle = '-', linewidth=1.5)

plt.show()
```

I've this error :

```
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-6e05a05d2dab> in <module>()
     76 A_lat_new = f(A_lon_new)
     77 
---> 78 A_x, A_y = map(A_lon, A_lat)
     79 A_x1, A_y1 = map(A_lon_new, A_lat_new)
     80 

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: Hi Koong, which line of code causes the error to be thrown?

Comment: The error means that some variable (name) is a numpy array, while the code assumes it is a function or method.  That could be because you have mis-read the documentation, but most likely its because that variable is not what you think it is.  But you/we need to identify which variable is causing the problem

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3?  Your use of `map` is probably wrong in Python 3.

Comment: ---> 78 A_x, A_y = map(A_lon, A_lat)  There is an error in this part.

Comment: When asking about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback in the question. Copy the Traceback and paste it in the question, then format it as code (select it and type ctrl-k)

Comment: I installed a python 2.7. but I still have problems. :(

Answer (score 4):

It looks like the offending line of code is

```
A_x, A_y = map(A_lon, A_lat)
```

The `map` function *applies* a function to some kind of list or iterable. E.g.

```
map(lambda x: 2*x, [1, 2, 3])
# [2, 4, 6]
```

The object in `A_lon` is definitely an array rather than a function. Are you trying to combine those two arrays together with a function like `zip`?